# How to install Memcached in a virtualenv

Tags: python

I'm trying to install the memcached python bindings in a virualenv:

```
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-196:~$ pip uninstall python-memcached
Cannot uninstall requirement python-memcached, not installed
(env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-196:~$ pip install python-memcached
Collecting python-memcached
  Using cached python-memcached-1.53.tar.gz
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-x1yj76g5/python-memcached/setup.py", line 4, in <module>
        import memcache
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):    

      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>    

      File "/tmp/pip-build-x1yj76g5/python-memcached/setup.py", line 4, in <module>    

        import memcache    

    ----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-x1yj76g5/python-me
mcached
```

How can I get this working

edit:

```
   Not searching http://www.tummy.com/Community/software/python-memcached/ (from https://pypi.python.
 org/simple/python-memcached/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
   Not searching http://www.tummy.com/Community/software/python-memcached/ (from https://pypi.python.
 org/simple/python-memcached/) for files because external urls are disallowed.
   Using version 1.53 (newest of versions: 1.53, 1.52, 1.51, 1.48, 1.47, 1.31)
   Using cached python-memcached-1.53.tar.gz
   Downloading from URL https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/python-memcached/python-memcached-1
 .53.tar.gz#md5=89570d26e7e7b15caa668a6b2678bd3c (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/python-memcache
 d/)
   Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-j_435lge/python-memcached/setup.py) egg_info for package pyt
 hon-memcached
     Running command python setup.py egg_info
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
       File "/tmp/pip-build-j_435lge/python-memcached/setup.py", line 4, in <module>
         import memcache
     Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
     Traceback (most recent call last):     

       File "<string>", line 20, in <module>     

       File "/tmp/pip-build-j_435lge/python-memcached/setup.py", line 4, in <module>     

         import memcache     

     ----------------------------------------
     Cleaning up...
     Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-j_435lge/python-me
 mcached
     Exception information:
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 232
 , in main
         status = self.run(options, args)
       File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", lin
 e 339, in run
         requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
       File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 385
 , in prepare_files
         req_to_install.run_egg_info()
       File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line
  358, in run_egg_info
         command_desc='python setup.py egg_info')
       File "/home/ubuntu/.virtualenvs/env1/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line
 749, in call_subprocess
         % (command_desc, proc.returncode, cwd))
     pip.exceptions.InstallationError: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in
  /tmp/pip-build-j_435lge/python-memcached     

 (env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-196:~$
```

edit 2:

```
 (env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-196:~$ sudo apt-get install memcached
 Reading package lists... Done
 Building dependency tree
 Reading state information... Done
 memcached is already the newest version.
 The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
   python-colorama python-distlib python-html5lib
 Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 70 not upgraded.
 (env1)ubuntu@ip-172-31-28-196:~$ pip install python-memcached
 Collecting python-memcached
   Using cached python-memcached-1.53.tar.gz
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
       File "/tmp/pip-build-k_28hio4/python-memcached/setup.py", line 4, in <module>
         import memcache
     Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
     Traceback (most recent call last):     

       File "<string>", line 20, in <module>     

       File "/tmp/pip-build-k_28hio4/python-memcached/setup.py", line 4, in <module>     

         import memcache     

     ----------------------------------------
     Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-k_28hio4/python-me
 mcached
```

Comment: Seems like an error hiding the actual problem. Try running pip install with -vvv, maybe we can get more info. If we look in the sources, memcache should be importable by setup.py, it only imports six, which should be solved dependency by then. It looks like memcache is raising some exception and becoming un-importable for you. Maybe untar the archive in python path and try to import the memcache module in it yourself, in interpreter.

Comment: Hi Mihnea, thanks for looking at this . Sorry what command should I run ? I can't find a reference to 'pip install with -vvv'

Comment: pip install -vvv python-memcached # that is, very very verbose output

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to install memcached first ?
Like with `sudo apt-get install memcached`

Comment: If the problem really comes from the line 4 of python-memcached setup.py (`import memcache`), then it is that your Python interpreter can't find the memcache.py module (the directory is not in Python path). A temporary solution would be to remove the line `import memcache` from setup.py, and replace `version=memcache.__version__` with `version="1.53"`, then use `python setup.py install`

Comment: Where is the setup.py file located? there is no "/tmp/pip-build-k_28hio4/python-memcached/setup.py". Not even a /tmp/pip-build-k_28hio4/

Comment: You can try to download the archive from PyPi (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-memcached/1.53) or with the download URL given on the same page. You will get the package with the setup.py file.

Comment: where should I download it to?